# Removing \r, \n and \t, from a string

Tags: r, regex

I have one string which looks like this :

```
"Způsob využití:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tobjekt k bydlení\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"
```

I am confused that how i suppose to clean it? i want to remove everything which looks like :

`\r`, `\n`, `\t`.

my output should be `Způsob využití: objekt k bydlení`

any help how i can achieve it? i am new to r and dont know much of it

Comment: `stringr::str_remove_all(x, "\\\t|\\\n|\\\r")`

Comment: Do you want to do this only on one single string or a vector of strings (eg. "column" of a `data.frame`)?

Comment: @DarrenTsai sorry i did not know that, done it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stringr::str_squish()`:

```r
stringr::str_squish(x)

# [1] "Způsob využití: objekt k bydlení"
```

It can be achieved with `base`:

```r
trimws(gsub('\\s+', ' ', x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stringr::str_remove_all(x, "\\t|\\n|\\r")
```

is answer thanks to @user438383

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub("\\n|\\t|\\r", "", "Způsob využití:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tobjekt k bydlení\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t")
[1] "Způsob využití:objekt k bydlení"
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post